# Is k8s dashboard recommended for production ready server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I saw many tutorials show how to setup k8s dashboard UI for development which will be access from localhost.

Can it be used for production server too? If yes, how to setup it on production master node?

Comment: You could set up an Ingress to access it. You will need to setup some pretty strict RBAC rules though. For authentication, you could use tokens or even integrate with ldap if you have that.

Comment: @jason-stanley I would create an nginx-ingress for my entire apps, can it (dashboard) just join to my nginx-ingress without creating a new ingress?

Comment: on GKE you can integrate Proxy Aware Identity with dashboard, prometheus or jaeger. For sample implementation https://github.com/acedemand/gke-advanced-features/tree/master/security/cloud-iap-integration